# IBM Netezza Driver for C#: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, netezza

I have been using the netezza driver in my application for a few months without issue.  However, today, it has been throwing the following issue...

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at NZdotNETTypes.NZdotNETTypesHelper.LoadTypesMappings(NZdotNETConnector conn, NZdotNETBackendTypeMapping TypeMappings, IEnumerable`1 TypeInfoList)
   at NZdotNETTypes.NZdotNETTypesHelper.CreateAndLoadInitialTypesMapping(NZdotNETConnector conn)
   at NZdotNET.NZdotNETConnector.Open()
   at NZdotNET.NZdotNETConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NZdotNETConnection Connection)
   at NZdotNET.NZdotNETConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnector(NZdotNETConnection Connection)
   at NZdotNET.NZdotNETConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NZdotNETConnection Connection)
   at NZdotNET.NZdotNETConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
```

This is happening both locally and on the server, with no code changes.

```
    try
        {
            var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("NZdotNET");

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                if (connection == null) return;
                connection.ConnectionString = ConfigHelper.IdpConnectionString;

                using (var command = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                    if (command == null) return;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = idpQuery;
                    command.CommandTimeout = ConfigHelper.ImportTaskCommandTimeout;
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    using (var adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter())
                    {
                        if (adapter == null) return;
                        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                        var dataTable = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                        Import(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't see anything obvious and I have broken the connection string down into key/value pairs using the ConnectionStringBuilder and I get the same issue.

Comment: Do you have access to the server?  Are there any errors logged in pg.log on the server side?

Comment: Have you changed your system locale recently by any chance? What is your current locale?

Comment: also please let us know the version numbers of both the .net driver and nps.

Comment: @MikeDeRoy - the version I have is: `<add name="NZdotNET Data Provider" invariant="NZdotNET" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for IBM Netezza Database Server" type="NZdotNET.NZdotNETFactory, NZdotNET, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>`

Comment: Was the version of the NPS server software updated. please check with your admin what the NPS version is.